# [c++]while(cin.get(str,size).get())... why infinit looping,rather than quit if i give a blank line

Tags: c++, while-loop

it's a c++ question.

```
char str[10];
while(cin.get(str,10).get())
    ...
cin.clear();
```

i hope when i give just the enter key, the while loop would end due to that the `cin.get(str,size)` would fail encountering the blank line. but when I add a `.get()` behind aim to read up the following \n, the while loop just keep looping when i give a blank line?
is it that the `.get()` causes the judgement true override the `cin.get(str,size)`'s false?

Answer (score 0):

`cin.get(str,10)` Extracts characters from the stream and stores them in str as a c-string, until either 9 characters have been extracted or the delimiting character is encountered, not "gets 10 and fails if it cant, because the line ended."

This will basically never "fail" until you get to the end of file. 
You will have to capture the line and test its length separately (probably not in the same expression)